# Searching value in already cache data from database in laravel

Tags: laravel, caching, redis

I am learning to make caching and as I know

```
if(cache::has('cacheKey')) {
    cache::get('cacheKey')
} else {
    $data=cache::remember('cacheKey',time,function() {
    return db::table('user')->get();});
    return $data; 
}
```

now question is when I am trying to search a specific data on key and then on result paginate that data for this I did use **Cache::remember** but how can make this fast when I am using all the time **cache::remember** function when I am trying to search in cache key, here is code

```
$page    = $req->has('page') ? $req->query('page') : 1;
$keyword = $req->keyword;

if(cache::has('FileData')) {
    if(!empty($keyword)) { 
        $file = cache::remember('FileData'.'search='.$keyword.'page='.$page,1440,function() use ($keyword) {
               return File::with('callcase','lettercase','update_table','fileimages')
                      ->where('id','Like','%'.$keyword.'%')
                      ->orWhere('file_name','Like','%'.$keyword.'%')
                      ->orWhere('recieved_by','Like','%'.$keyword.'%')
                      ->orWhere('processed_by','Like','%'.$keyword.'%')
                      ->orWhere('address','Like','%'.$keyword.'%')
                      ->orWhere('contact_no','Like','%'.$keyword.'%')
                      ->orWhere('show_status','Like','%'.$keyword.'%')
                      ->orWhere('Reopen','Like','%'.$keyword.'%')
                      ->orderBy('id','desc')
                      ->paginate(25)
                      ->setpath('');
                });

        $file->appends(['keyword'=>$keyword]);
        if(count($file)>0) {    
            return view('home')->with('files',$file) ;
        } else { 
            $error = "File does not found , Search another using keyword ";
            return view('home')->with('filemsg',$error);
        }
    } else {
            $file = cache::remember('FileData'.'page='.$page,1440,function () {
                    return File::with('callcase','lettercase','update_table','fileimages')
                           ->orderBy('id','desc')
                           ->paginate(25);});
                return view('home')->with('files',$file) ;
        }   
} else {
            $file = cache::remember('FileData',1440,function(){
                   return File::with('callcase','lettercase','update_table','fileimages')
                          ->orderBy('id','desc')
                          ->paginate(25);
            });
            return view('home')->with('files',$file);
}
```

My code is working fine and returning data as i wanted but i am confused on this when every time i am making remember data then how can i make that faster it would faster when i will retrieve data from already cache key and search in them and paginate them , How can i do this and help me if somehow i am doing wrong.